# spectrum of a special class of tridiagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a real and symmetric tridiagonal matrix with zero diagonals and where subdiagonals and superdiagonals are equal to 1 except the (1,2)-th component being equal to $a$, i.e.,

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & a & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\  &  & & \ddots \\0 & \cdots & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$

For $a=1$ the spectrum is $2 cos(πj/(n+1)), j=1,\ldots,n$. I want to determine its spectrum for $a\neq1$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $a>0$, you can symmetrise the matrix so that its $(1,2)$-th and $(2,1)$-th entries are $\sqrt{a}$. I don't know if there are any closed-form solutions for the eigenvalues, except in very special cases. E.g. when $n$ is odd, $0$ must be an eigenvalue; when $a = 4 - 2(n-2)/(n-1)$, $\pm2$ are eigenvalues.